# Calling a Method from View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm just getting start with ASP.NET MVC. I'm having below in my controller class.

```
 public ActionResult Test()
        {
           return View();
        }



        public string MyName()
        {
            return "chamara";
        }
```

How can i print the return value from MyName() method on my Test view?

Comment: pass it to your view in a model or ViewBag

Comment: The tag says they're using MVC 2, so it would be ViewData["MyName"] or a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, modify the `Test()` action like so:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    ViewData["MyName"] = "chamara";

    return View();
}
```

Then in the `Test.aspx` view, you can display the name with `<%= ViewData["MyName"] %>`.

Even better, as Dave A alludes to in his comment, would be to create a model with the information you want to display and create a strongly-typed view that knows how to display that information.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me would be the `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction` helpers

A good resource (albeit a bit old) is [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx)